# Maximizing and minimizing dot products

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, inner-products, lagrange-multiplier

Given 2 vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $\|u\| = 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i= c$ where $c<1$, I would like to maximize $$\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log (v_i)$$ and minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log (u_i)$$.
The answer in my opinion is $-c\log(c)$ if $c<1/e$ (and $c\log(c)$ for the minimum). I think so because on $[-1/e, 1/e]$ the function is monotonic (not sure of that). However I can't find formal proof of that, and I'll be glad for help

Comment: Hi. Which are knowns and which are unknowns and what are we optimizing with respect to? Also, what have you tried so far in trying to solve the problem?

Comment: The vectors u and v are unknown, I know the norm of u and sum of coordinates of v. I tried lagrange multipliers but it didn't work and confusing so I didn't write the equations here.

Comment: What function is monotonic? Anyway, I agree that this is a Lagrange multipliers problem. Rewrite the constraint on $u$ as $u_1^2+u_2^2+\ldots + u_n^2=1$, it is easier to differentiate

Comment: Xlogx on [-1/e, 1/e] is monotonic. I tried to rewrite the constraint as you wrote but it doesn't work as well

Comment: So is $x$ known or unknown?

Comment: Known, the x in the comment isn't the x from the question. Bad notation, I should have written c in the question, editing it now

Comment: I have scribbled down some computations - it looks ugly, agreed. You have two multipliers $\lambda, \mu$ and the Lagrange system $$\begin{cases} 2\lambda u_i = v_i\log(v_i) \\ \mu= u_i(1+\log v_i) \\ \sum u_i^2 =1 \\ \sum v_i = x\end{cases}$$ But note that there are singular points on your constraint. If $u_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, the Jacobian matrix of the constraints $\sum u_i^2=1, \sum v_i=1$ has rank 1. I suspect that the sought maximum is attained precisely there. HTH

Comment: Does this solution depend on n?

Comment: You implicitly assume $u, v> 0$, don't you?

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy Schwarz on the first one?

Comment: I do assume that. I didn't try Cauchy Schwarz - how can it help?

Comment: @JamesF. I post an answer for the first one. The second one might be ugly...

Comment: Can I use some symmetry argument to claim that the minimum is -1*maximum?

Comment: @JamesF.: probably not, because the constraints are different.

Comment: wait, are you trying to minimize and maximize the both sums at the same time or separately? That is, is it some kind of multiobjective problem ?

Comment: Originally, I want to maximize $$\sum_{i=0}^n u_iv_i \log(\frac{v_i}{u_i})$$. I thought it simpler to look at it as I wrote (max - min, as above). Maybe I am wrong and it's easier to look at it like this...

Comment: @JamesF. With which kind of constraints? Just $u_i,v_i > 0$? Probably you should post that as a new question.

Comment: Same constraints as before: the norm of u is 1 (and all it's coordinates are positive) and the sum of coordinates of v is c . Edit this post or write entirely new one? I don't wanna spam the forum

Comment: a new post and add links to the new one. Because multi object optimization is way different than single object optimization. You shouldn't make fundamental changes to a question with answers.

Comment: Here is a link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720292/maximize-with-constraints-of-vector-product

Answer (score 0):

**A hint** could be to write the expressions as functions $f$ and $g$:

$$f({\bf u},{\bf v}) =  \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log (v_i) \\
g({\bf u}, {\bf v}) = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log (u_i)$$

and then use partial differentiation and set the gradient of both to 0 and see where it leads. If necessary (and possible) then add the constraint that the hessians (matrices of partial second order differentials) should be positive resp. negative definite.

For the equality constraints as Giuseppe proposed we can add lagrange multipliers $$\lambda_1\|{\bf v}^t{\bf 1}-c\|, \lambda_2 \|{\bf u}^t{\bf u}-1\|$$
And maybe a barrier function for $c<1$ constraint if $c$ is also an unknown.

As we want the gradients to be zero vectors a candidate total function to minimize would be:

$$\min_{\bf u,v}\left\{\|\nabla f({\bf u , v})\| + \|\nabla g({\bf u,v})\| + \lambda_1\|{\bf v}^t{\bf 1}-c\| + \lambda_2 \|{\bf u}^t{\bf u}-1\|\right\}$$

For some suitable norm(s).

Comment: This ignores the constraints (which make it harder, if I didn't have them this question was about maximizing entropy which is easy to do). As I wrote in the previous comment, I tried solving it with lagrange multipliers but it doesn't work (the lagrange variables don't cancel out)

Comment: This approach disregards the constraints.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot the constraints, added an approach for them now.

Comment: It is not me who proposed the Lagrange multipliers actually! :-) James F mentioned them in his original post already.

Comment: How can I derive that expressions?