# Find the extrema of $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log \left| \frac{v_i}{u_i} \right|$

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, inner-products, lagrange-multiplier

This question is similar to the following one: [Maximizing and minimizing dot products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720015/maximizing-and-minimizing-dot-products?noredirect=1#comment3511874_1720015).
 However there are significant differences, hence I opened a new question.

Maximize and minimize

$$\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log \left| \frac{v_i}{u_i} \right|$$

such that $u,v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with $\|u\| = 1$ ,$u_i > 0, v_i \geq -c_2$ where $c_2$ is a small positive number, and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i= c$ where $c<1$.

The result in my opinion is $-c \log c$ for the maximum and $c \log c$ for the minimum. I tried solving it with Lagrange multipliers, but it doesn't work out, I'll be glad for help.

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are given, there is nothing to maximize/minimize.

Comment: I edited the question @grew

Comment: are you sure about $u_i\ge 0$? Not $u_i > 0$? Otherwise you may have $0/0$.

Comment: Edited it as well, thanks

Comment: do you assume $c>0$?

Comment: Yes, but very close to 0

Answer (score 0):

**This is an answer to the problem with the constraint $v_i \ge 0$ and $n>1$.**

Let $g(t) = t\log(t)$ for $t>0$ and $g(0)=0$, which is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly convex.

We can rephrase the problem with $v_i = u_i t_i$ and obtain the equivalent problem
$$ f(u,t) = \sum_i u_i^2 g(t_i) $$
subject to
$\|u\| = 1$, $u_i > 0$, $\sum_i u_i t_i = c$, $t_i \ge 0$, where $c\in(0,1)$ is fixed.
Now, we can obtain following maximizer analytically:

Fix a $u\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\|u\| = 1$ and $0 < u_1 \le \dotsb u_n \le 1$.
Let $f_u(t) = f(u,t) = \sum_i u_i^2 g(t_i)$.

1. As $g$ is continuous and convex, so is $f_u$ continuous convex on the compact and convex set $S_u = \{ t\in\mathrm R^n \mid t_i \ge 0, \sum_i u_i t_i = c \}$.
   Thus, the global maximum of $f_u$ is attained by an extreme point of $S_u$.
   That is, 
   $$ \sup_{t\in S_u} f_u(t) = \max_{1\le i \le n} f_u\left( \frac c {u_i} e_i \right) = \max_{1\le i \le n} u_i^2 g\left( \frac c {u_i} \right).$$
2. Now consider $h(s) = s^2 g(c/s) = sc \log(c/s)$ for $s>0$ and $h(0) = 0$. We have $h'(s) = 0$ if and only if $s = c/e$, that is
   $$ \max_{0\le s \le 1} h(s) = \max\{ h(0), h(c/e), h(1) \} = \max\left\{0, \frac{c^2}{e}, c\log(c) \right\} = \frac{c^2}{e}. $$
3. That is, we have 
   $$ \sup f = \sup_{u} \sup_{t\in S_u} f_u(t) \le \frac{c^2}{e},$$ 
   which is attainable **in case of $n>1$** by some $(u, t)$ with $u_n = c/e$, $t_n = e$, and $t_1=\dotsb = t_{n-1} = 0$.

**Note:** 
With the constraints $v_i \ge -c2$, the objective function won't be convex in $t_i = v_i/u_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I added the assumption that all $v_i$ are positive

Comment: Edit that again, I want each $v_i > -c2$ where c2 is small positive

Comment: @JamesF. Do you really need that? $v_i > 0$ was easier :D

Comment: A solution for v>0 will also be great

Comment: If you have one I'll be thankful

Comment: @JamesF.: I edited the answer.

Comment: @JamesF.: fixed the answer. the maximizer was only valid for $n>1$.